# inequality involving norms and integrals

Tags: integration, inequality, normed-spaces

For a square integrable function $f$, is the following true, and if so under what circumstances?
\begin{equation}
\left\Vert \int_{a}^{b}f\left(t\right)dt\right\Vert _{2}\leq\int_{a}^{b}\left\Vert f\left(t\right)\right\Vert _{2} dt
\end{equation}
Also under what circumstances is equality guaranteed? Any help / suggestions are greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\phi$ be a linear functional, then 
$|\phi(\int f)| = |\int \phi(f)| \le \int \|\phi\| \|f\|$, since
$|\phi(f(t))| \le \|\phi\| \|f(t)\|$.

Hence if $\|\phi\| \le 1$, then we have
$| \phi(\int f) | \le \int \|f\|$.

Now note that $\|x\| = \sup_{\|\phi\| \le 1} |\phi(x)|$, hence
$\|\int f\| \le \int \|f\|$.

Here is a strong hint for the second part:

If $f$ takes values in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $\|\int f\| = \int \|f\|$, then
there is some $\phi$ with $\|\phi\| = 1$ such that
$\phi(\int f) = \int \phi(f) = \int \|f\|$, and so we must have $\phi(f(t)) = \|f(t)\|$ ae. Since we can write
$\phi(x) = \langle g, x \rangle$ for some $g$, we see that we must have
$f(t) = \|f(t)\| g$ for ae. $t$.

Comment: Thanks @copper.hat, really appreciate it. I take it this applies to all norms (not just the 2-norm)? Furthermore is the statement $\left|\phi\left(f\left(t\right)\right)\right|\leq\left\Vert \phi\right\Vert \left\Vert f\left(t\right)\right\Vert$ from the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality?

Comment: The first part applies to all induced norms (so, by definition $\|\phi\| = \sup_{\|x\|\le 1} |\phi(x)|$). From this we get $|\phi(x)| \le \|\phi\| \|x\|$.  The equality part above relies on the 2 norm.

Comment: You are very welcome.